# How to insert serialized data into database using rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, serialization, console

I added dynamic form fields to my rails app folowing the tutorial on this link
[railscasts](http://www.railscasts.com/episodes/403) or [youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t_FNKR7jahM) and the source code [github](https://github.com/railscasts/403-dynamic-forms)

creating/updating using forms data works well as expected. however, I get the following error

```
undefined method `humanize' for :author:Symbol
```

when I try viewing the product inserted using console with this command for example

```
Product.create(product_type_id: 1, name: "refactoring", price: 24.99, properties: {author: "Martin Fowler", page_count: 197, paperback: 1 } )
```

examining the database I noticed that the data inserted through the console doesn't get serialized

**example data submitted through form:**

```
--- !ruby/hash:ActionController::Parameters
author: Martin Fowle
page_count: '197'
paperback: '1'
```

**example data submitted through console:**

```
---
:author: Martin Fowle
:page_count: '197'
:paperback: '1'
```

How can I get this to work?

I need this because I would also like to be able to update products using data from external sources, like data from APIs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data is being serialized through console, but you are passing different object, just normal hash and in your controller it is `ActionController::Parameters` objects.

Try something like this in console:

```
Product.create(product_type_id: 1, name: "refactoring", price: 24.99, properties: ActionController::Parameters.new({author: "Martin Fowler", page_count: 197, paperback: 1 }) )
```